# javascript functions calls in order, made by JSP

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, jsp, synchronous

In my JSP file, I create several calls to the same javascript function (setURL function).

**JSP File**

```
<script src="js/webGL.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
        <%
            Brazo brazo = brazoDAO.getBrazo(id);

            List<Pieza> piezas = brazo.getPiezas();

            int i=piezas.size()-1;
            while(i>=0)
            {
                String url=piezas.get(i).getUrl();
                String tipo=piezas.get(i).getTipo_fk().getNombre();
                List<SubPieza> subPiezas = piezas.get(i).getSubPiezas();
                int u=0;
                while(u<subPiezas.size())
                {
                    String conf=subPiezas.get(u).getConf().toString();
                    int n = subPiezas.get(u).getOrden();
                    %>          
                    setURL(<%="\""+url+"/"+tipo+"/"+tipo+n+".json\""%>,<%=conf%>);
                    <%
                    u++;
                }
                i--;
            }
        %>          
    </script>
```

This is the javascript function setURL. This function is in webGL.js file

**WebGL.js**

```
function setURL(url, conf)
{   
 loader.load(url, function(geometry,materials)
 {
    // some code        
 });    
}
```

When I debug the javascript files, I see that the order of calls is different than JSP file have.

How can I make the calls in order?

Thank you

-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+

**EDIT**

This is what HTML have

```
<script type="text/javascript">

                    setURL("./models/kl250-3/hand/hand1.json","pos:0,0,0;rot:0,0,0;sca:1,1,1;lim:0,1;");

                    setURL("./models/kl250-3/hand/hand2.json","pos:0,0,0;rot:0,0,0;sca:1,1,1;lim:0,1;");

                    setURL("./models/kl250-3/elbow/elbow1.json","pos:0,0,0;rot:0,0,0;sca:1,1,1;lim:0,2;");

                    setURL("./models/kl250-3/elbow/elbow2.json","pos:0,0,0;rot:0,0,0;sca:1,1,1;lim:0,1;");

                    setURL("./models/kl250-3/base/base1.json","pos:0,0,0;rot:0,0,0;sca:1,1,1;lim:0,0;");

                    setURL("./models/kl250-3/base/base2.json","pos:0,0,0;rot:0,0,0;sca:1,1,1;lim:4,0;");

    </script>
```

Soo the expected order of calls is: hand1, hand2, elbow1, elbow2, base1, base2

Inside setUrl() I put a console.log(url) to see the order. This is the order that are made the calls.

1. ./models/kl250-3/mano/mano1.json
2. ./models/kl250-3/antebrazo/antebrazo2.json
3. ./models/kl250-3/mano/mano2.json
4. ./models/kl250-3/base/base1.json
5. ./models/kl250-3/base/base2.json
6. ./models/kl250-3/antebrazo/antebrazo1.json

And the must funny is that if I reload the page, the order is diferent.

-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+

**SOLUTION**

objectCount starts at 0

```
function setURL(url, conf)
{   
 var currentOrder=objectCount;
 objectCount+=1;

 var modelo = new THREE.Mesh();
 modelo.index=currentOrder;
 objectsArray[currentOrder]=modelo;

 loader.load(url, function(geometry,materials)
 {
    //some code
 });    
}
```

I added another function to use the array and now all work.

Thank you all for your answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have an array in js of all the urls first.

```
var arr;
int i = 0;
function setURL(url, conf)
{   
    arr[i] = url; 
    i++;
}
```

Then process them at the end one by one by reading the array.
Once one request finished, execute the other one.

**OR**

There are alternatives rather to use load(), you can opt for [$.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) directly if you need additional control over what .load() offers like **async="false"**.

Also others like:

- $.get()
- $.getJSON()
- $.getScript()
- $.post()

Comment: Your answer helped me to get the solution. Is a little different. I edit the question to add the solution

Answer (score 0):

`Javascript` is always(and already in your case) synchronous. The loading and success function trigger, depends on the url you load in various calls. If the url content is less and  loaded faster, its success functions gets executed first.

Check your source html of the page. You can see your `setURL(` functions are in the exact same order as you formed in the JSP code.

But `loader.load` is asynchronous. Means, It starts the json file download for the first file, and It won't wait for it to complete. It starts executing the second command. So the success function depends on which finishes the load first. The order is in a row of files which finishes load faster. To make it synchronous, you have to check for option in `.load` statement. For e-g similar command $.ajax has the following option `$.ajax({ async: false,`

Comment: Hi an thanks for your answer. I edited the question to add the HTML after his load.

Comment: Yes this is expected. Because, `loader.load` is asynchronous. Means, It starts the json file download for the first file, and It won't wait for it to complete. It starts executing the second command. So the success function depends on which finishes the load first. The order is in a row of files which finishes load faster. To make it synchronous, you have to check for option in `.load` statement. For e-g similar command $.ajax has the following option `$.ajax({  async: false,`